# Creating an array of points from SQL Server database c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, point

I am quite new to c# and have stored positions of an object in a SQL Server database. I have written a query to select the object locations out of the database and now want to populate an array with these.

I have had trouble with 'you cannot convert an object to a point' etc errors and I cannot figure out how to populate an array with the point data type.

Could anyone help me with this?

Current code:

```
 try
 {
    consecond.Open(); //Opens the connection
    SqlDataReader dr = com_getposition.ExecuteReader();
    int i = 0;
    object[] arrayreturn = new object[10];
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        arrayreturn[i] = dr["POSITION"];
        i++;
    }
    p1.Location = (Point)arrayreturn[0];
    dr.Close();
 }
 finally
 {
     consecond.Close(); //Closes the connection
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: please provide the code you have written so far

Comment: What type is `POSITION` in the sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `POSITION` is of type `nvarchar` you need to parse it (not cast it) into correct type.

```
var str = (string)dr["POSITION"];
var i = str.IndexOf(',', 3);
var x = int.Parse(str.Substring(3, i  - 3));
var y = int.Parse(str.Substring(i + 3, str.Length - (i + 4)));
p1.Location = new Point(x, y);
```

Comment: Data is stored like this in the DB (as visual studio shows): {X=390,Y=197}"

Answer (score 0):

Magnus is correct, but personally I prefer something like this:

```
Int32 n;
bool b = Int32.TryParse(arrayreturn[0].ToString(), out n);
if (b)
    p1.Location = n;
```

If `location` is a Point, then you can modify this:

```
Int32 x;
Int32 y;

bool b = Int32.TryParse(arrayreturn[0].ToString(), out x);
if (b) {
    b = Int32.TryParse(arrayreturn[1].ToString(), out y);
    if (b) {
        p1.Location = new Point(x, y);
        return;
    }
}

// put error-handling code here
```